# console.log the result of eval gives more info than just the result of eval in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If you are in the Chrome console, how come you get different outputs when explicitly console-logging the result of eval:

```
eval("/(\\d)/.exec('1')");               // output: ["1", "1"]

console.log(eval("/(\\d)/.exec('1')"));  // output: ["1", "1", index: 0, input: "1"]
```

Comment: `/(\d)/.exec('1')` and `console.log(/(\d)/.exec('1'))` . The same thing.